# Why using tabs with Console.WriteLine don't show background color?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, .net-6.0

When you print tabs using `Console.WriteLine`, they never use the specified background color:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("No tabs, no spaces");
Console.WriteLine("\tTabs don't have background color");
Console.WriteLine("    Spaces have background color");
```

[image]

Did I miss something or is it by design?

Comment: by [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=net-6.0]) "the color that appears behind each character" - tab isn't character

Comment: @s-s tab is a character

Comment: What console app/platform?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have updated question tags.

Comment: "property affects only output that is written to individual character cells", meybe tab is not individual character cells

Comment: Did a quick test and can't help but notice that the characters rendered in the console output are 8 spaces, not one tab. If I had to make an educated guess I'd speculate that it's got something to do with how tabs are rendered onto console and maybe some kind of native process in the windows console itself that replaces the tab with 8 spaces but doesn't honor the color format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing it looks like this is related to how the native Visual Studio debugger renders the output and is not by fault of your code or app.

e.g. See below a side by side running a sample through the debugger vs directly through command line.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it, I did the same exact test and was going to update my question!

Comment: I accept your answer because I don't think that can be solved at all.